# Ubuntu Software Update Application Always Fails GNOME Application Platform version 3.34 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, updates

```
ID                                        Arch   Branch Op Remote  Download
 1.     org.gnome.Platform                x86_64 3.34   u  flathub < 318.4 MB
 2.     org.gnome.Platform.Locale         x86_64 3.34   u  flathub < 322.7 MB (partial)
 3.     org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 x86_64 19.08  i  flathub < 593.4 kB
```

So I should not install these into Ubuntu 18.04. correct?

This shows in terminal. like this -> `$ flatpak update`

also you can do in terminal to check  -> `$ flatpak repair`

you will see:

```
Verifying flathub:runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs/x86_64/18.08…

Verifying deploy/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs/x86_64/18.08…

Skipping non-deployed ref flathub:runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08…
```

these three maybe a problems of updating fails on Ubuntu Software Application.

---

**EDIT:**

I've already tried $ `flatpak update`. Then Ubuntu Software Application Stopped to say what there is update.

Ubuntu Software Application can not update what flatpak want, but it shows there is update.

Using terminal $ `flatpak update` work correctly.

Comment: `flatpak update` should return: `Looking for updates…
Nothing to do.` If that is not what it shows now, it did not work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this post on ubuntu-fr.org](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2043959)

First, run the following command:

```
flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264
```

Then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when it asks: "use this remote"

If you get an error, run the following command:

```
flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08
```

Then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when it asks: "use this remote" and then run the following:

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
flatpak update
```

Comment: mchid hello, I have the same situation with my Ubuntu 18.04.3 laptop. I tried to solve it using both commands of your advices (i.e. ''flatpak install org freedesktop.Platform ....) in the same order as you advice. Unfortunately after both commands I get the same result: '' error: REMOTE and REF must be specified ''.  Brgds

Comment: @Kapel You need to run: `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo` and you should get a password prompt. [The instructions are found here](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/).

Comment: @Kapel If that is already done and you still get the error, then specify flathub like in this example: `flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264` and `flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08`

Comment: mchid hello, Thank you for your additional advices of today (2.12.2019): This is what I did: 1.) I installed Flatpak as in instruction page, 2.) I specified the flathub - in my case it was the 2nd one (i.e. ..._64/19.08). Then I ran commands 3.) flatpak uninstall --unused and flatpak update. After installation completed I ran 4.) Looking for updates…and I got the following result 5.) ''Nothing to do''. So, now this application update should be OK. Many thanks to you !!!

Comment: "flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo"
should be added to the answer